# My cart item reappears after again while clicking on view cart button in android studio

Tags: android, listview, duplicates, cart

I am beginner to android, i am creating a e-commerce app where a user clicking on add_to_cart button one cart item is added but when i clicks on view cart button  ONE cart item  is now added in "MY CART PAGE" later i press back button and Again click on view cart button TWO  same cart items are now available of same product without clicking on add_to_cart button

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"


    tools:context=".CartdetailsActivity">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/cart_toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/Action"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="You have 2 product in cart"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/cart_count"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp">

    </TextView>
    <ListView

        android:id="@+id/cartlist"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

    </ListView>
    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:id="@+id/continue_to_shop"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"

        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Continue Shopping"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalprice"
            android:text="BACK"
            android:background="#89cff0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="154dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp">

        </TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/proceed"
            android:layout_width="155dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Proceed">

        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> CODE

```
public class CartdetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static ArrayList<CartItem> cartItems=cartItems=new ArrayList<CartItem>();


    public CartsAdapter cartAdapter=new CartsAdapter(cartItems,this);

    ListView addtocart;
    String seller_nam,prodlabel,proimag;
    int procost;
    TextView spinner,totall,cartcount;
    //Button deletebtn;
    int val,prod_id;
    int total=0;
    Button checkout, continue_shopping,viewbtn,ok,cancel;
    String cart_activity="cart";
    int count=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cartdetails);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.cart_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("TRADEGLIMPSE");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        addtocart = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cartlist);
        // deletebtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.delet);
        checkout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.proceed);
        //spinner=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        cartcount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cart_count);
        continue_shopping = (Button) findViewById(R.id.continue_to_shop);



        totall = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalprice);
        SharedPreferences pref1 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("sellername", 0);
        if (pref1.getString("seller_name", " ") != " ") {
            seller_nam = pref1.getString("seller_name", " ");
            Log.wtf("prosellername", seller_nam);
        }


        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref5", 0);
        prod_id = pref.getInt("productid", 0);
        prodlabel = pref.getString("shop_name", " ");
        procost = pref.getInt("cost", 0);
        proimag = pref.getString("img", " ");
        Log.wtf("prolabel......", prodlabel);
        SharedPreferences pref2 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("valuee", 0);
        if (pref2.getInt("val", 0) != 0) {
            val = pref2.getInt("val", 0);
        }
        if (val == 1) {
            checkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(CartdetailsActivity.this, OrderNowActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        } else {
            checkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CartdetailsActivity.this);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.quantity_dialog);
                    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    dialog.setCancelable(false);
                    Button cancelbtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelbutton);
                    Button okbtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.okbuton);
                    cancelbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    okbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(CartdetailsActivity.this, LoginpageActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("cart", cart_activity);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();


                }
            });
        }
        SharedPreferences pref6 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("review", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref6.edit();
        edit.putInt("product_id",prod_id);
        edit.putString("product_label", prodlabel);
        edit.putInt("product_cost", procost);
        edit.putString("product_imag", proimag);
        edit.putString("seller_name", seller_nam);
        edit.apply();

        addtocart.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"item clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                cartItems.remove(position);
                cartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }

        });




    CartItem item = new CartItem(prodlabel, procost, proimag, seller_nam, prod_id);
    cartItems.add(item);
    cartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


        @Override
        protected void onResume () {
            super.onResume();

            addtocart.setAdapter(cartAdapter);
            cartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          //  String text= String.valueOf(cartAdapter.getCount());
            //cartcount.setText("You have "+text+" product in cart");
    }
}
```

> Adapter

```
public class CartsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public static ArrayList<CartItem> CartItems;
    Context context;
     increment increment;

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    int total;
    public CartsAdapter(ArrayList<CartItem> cartItems, Context context) {
        this.CartItems=cartItems;
        this.context=context;

    }

    public CartsAdapter(increment increment) {
        this.CartItems=cartItems;
        this.increment=increment;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return CartItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return CartItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public interface increment {
        void addcount(boolean flag);
    }


    private  class ViewHolder{
        TextView productname,shopname,price,totall;
        ImageView image;
        //Button deletebtn;
        Spinner quant;


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.singlecartitem, parent,false);
            holder.productname=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cart_dress);
            holder.shopname=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.shopname);
            holder.price=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
           // holder.deletebtn=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delet);
            holder.quant=(Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quanti);
            holder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cart_image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final CartItem row_pos=CartItems.get(position);
        holder.productname.setText(row_pos.getProduct_name());
        holder.shopname.setText(row_pos.getShop_name());
        String imgg=row_pos.getProduct_img();
        Picasso.with(context).load(imgg).into(holder.image);
        return convertView;

    }
}
```

Comment: You should rephrase and post a more specific technical question instead of business logic of your app

Answer (score 0):

First, clear your ArrayList before populating

*example:*
yourArrayList.clear()

Comment: i used arraylist.clear() ,old cart item will be replaced by newly added cart item

Comment: The issue is coming from

`CartItem item = new CartItem(prodlabel, procost, proimag, seller_nam, prod_id);
    cartItems.add(item);
    cartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

comment out that line, it you're adding items to the array without any click listener...

Comment: True!! now i  have added on click listener  but now i have to check the product id ie if added product id ==current product id